# Kali Linux Does Not Start Up Properly

Tags: kali-linux, live-usb, debian-installer

I'm a bit of a Linux noob, but have installed other Linux OS's before. Kali is the only one that has given me some trouble though. I've installed Ubuntu, CentOS, and Pop!_OS on different partitions before. However, I turned my attention to Kali.

I downloaded both `amd64` versions of both Kali and Debian and used Rufus 3.8 to create a live USB. Both OS's work fine as live USB's, but do not install properly into my partitions.

**Steps I have taken:**

I downloaded the 64-bit Kali Linux 2019.3 Rufus 3.8. I wrote the .iso file using ISO mode first. It installed everything properly until I reached the ethernet portion (my laptop doesn't have an ethernet card/port), so I selected `no ethernet card`. I also had problems with `configure the network`. The installation would come to a complete stop at this point and forced me to restart the installation. I used the advanced graphic installer and skipped `configure the network` and finished the rest of the installation. When I started Kali's boot loader, it would go to a black screen and spew out several lines of code. The screen would then turn black and have a white cursor on the top left corner. I eventually started over and wrote the .iso file using DD mode. The same problems occurred and skipped the same steps. Kali would finish installing, but then go back to the black screen.

To add insult to injury, I can boot Kali with my USB and look at all the files created in the partition.

I'm at a loss at this point and would like to hear some suggestions from anybody. I have a video that shows what code is being spewed out during the black screen if anyone needs to take a look:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Far5nGRDicU

Comment: Top lines, "_resuming from hibernation_". Clear that out and try a clean boot.

Comment: @roaima How do I clear it out?

Comment: @DavidRosas Press `e` in grub to edit the selected entry and add `noresume` to the kernel boot options at the end of the line (that's the line starting with `linux /boot/vmlinuz-5.2…` or similar, see [this example](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters)). Then boot with Ctrl-X or F10.

Comment: @Freddy I was able to login, but the laptop powers down afterwards